# How to set specific time in Toast?

Tags: java, android

Can I display a toast message based on user's current time?

I need to make an app, Where when I open the screen from 1:00 am to 11:00 am it will display the toast message "Good morning" whereas if I open the screen at 6:00 pm to 11:00 pm it will display the toast "good night"

```
public class ToastDisplay extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Good Morning",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: explain more details, your question is not clear. What do you mean by setting a specific time in toast?

Comment: He means the time user opens the phone. So if the user does it around mornings vs. night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do i use `Calendar` class to get the current time. Check the time and display the toast accordingly.

```
Calendar currentTime = Calender.getInstance();
int hour = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if(Use your condition here) {
    Display toast
} else if(Use your other condition) {
    Display toast
}
```

Just a note, your `hour` would be in 24 hour format so you need to check keeping that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> int toastDurationInMilliSeconds = 10000;

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT is int, so you have to declare new int